# Use Magic Trackpad 2 with Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, magic-trackpad

I was wondering if there's a way to take advantage of the gestures of my new Magic Trackpad 2 while using Google Chrome on OS X El Capitan.

The force touch is completely useless there, and Chrome is the app I use most of the time when I'm at my desk :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Chromium is working on :

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=550484

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=481890

> UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2376.0
>   Safari/537.36
>
> Steps to reproduce the problem:
>   1. Use a Macbook Pro or Macbook (2015) with an Apple Force Touch Trackpad
>   2. Click on a hyperlink, and push down (i.e. to trigger the second link)
>
> What is the expected behavior? Apple has recently introduced new
>   trackpads on their machines that have multiple levels of "click":
>
> https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204352
>
> In Safari, when you click hard (Force Click) on a linked page, a popup
>   window will appear, showing a preview of the hyperlinked page.
>
> When you Force Click on a link image, the image will appear in a
>   popup.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to try this technology with experimental library you can do it on Firefox (Gecko):

[developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch/force).

Note that this is an experimental technology, so syntax and behavior could change early in future versions.